# App working in IOS 5.0 but not on IOS 5.1

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, ios-simulator, stanford-nlp

I am trying to test an app from that I created by following an tutorial of Paul Hegarty from stanford university.

You can find a download link over [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs193p/cgi-bin/drupal/system/files/sample_code/Photomania_0.zip).

When I test it on the IOS5.0 simulator, it works fine. But when I test it on the IOS 5.1 simulator. It doesn't do anything. Can anybody test it in their simulators and tell me if it's working?

You only need to download it, and fill this API-key. In FlickrAPI-key.h

```
95f1f522e7332485662d0b1dfbba6544
```

Kind regards.

Comment: I am not sure if you'll get many responses telling you if the app worked on a simulator or not. You could probably add more detail - what happens? Where does the program stall off? Are there any error logs etc. Or you could try and debug the app. See where it stops

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This indeed doesn't work in the iOS 5.1 Simulator.

The (first) problem seems to be in PhotographersTableViewController.m on line 76, where `openWithCompletionHandler:` is being called on a `UIManagedDocument`, but for some reason, the completion handler is never called, even though it should be, [according to the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIDocument_Class/UIDocument/UIDocument.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010879-CH2-SW5).

Others have had this problem, too:

- [UIManagedDocument OpenWithCompletionHandler never returns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12439528/uimanageddocument-openwithcompletionhandler-never-returns)
- [UIManagedDocument CompletionHandler not executed in iOS 5.1
  simulator but works on device and iOS 6.0 simulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12577672/uimanageddocument-completionhandler-not-executed-in-ios-5-1-simulator-but-works)
- [Bug in iPhone Simulator 5.1 with Xcode 4.5 using
  UIManagedDocument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12557442/bug-in-iphone-simulator-5-1-with-xcode-4-5-using-uimanageddocument)

Looks like a bug in iOS 5.1 to me - but probably just in the Simulator, and maybe only when using the iOS 6.0 SDK. I don't have a device with iOS 5.1 with me, so I can't test that, but it seems to work fine on the iOS 6.0 Simulator.

Comment: Thank you for your response. What do you suggest for solve this problem?

Comment: @SarahGeebelen Get a device and test it there. The simulator is just a simulator and not an emulator after all.

Comment: @SarahGeebelen Don't use the iOS 5.1 Simulator. :) You most likely won't be able to fix this easily, as it looks to be a problem in Apple's code. Use the iOS 6.0 Simulator or a real device.

Comment: Okay tomorrow I have a device with IOS 5.1 and then I will test it. Thanks in advance.